# Being in "Reviewer invited" state for 3 months, What could it say?

Tags: publications, peer-review

For a math journal, after 4 weeks of submission, the status went from "with editor" to "reviewer invited", and its been in that particular state for the past 3 months. If you have any editorial experience, I'd like to know when would this kind of state happens, and does it say anything about the manuscript content, especially why the editor is finding hard to get the reviewers accept invitation, or is it that the reviewers for the subject matter of the paper, are rare to find?

Edit : more informtion

I have enquired. The Editorial Manager assured me that the Editor is carefully following and taking good care of the review process. What I have seen in earlier communication with Editor, I have no reason to doubt his interest in the manuscript. He seemed very much interested.

[Earlier communication with Editor in Chief](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/125267/102868)

Comment: If the journal staff say there is no problem, then the editor is having a hard time finding a reviewer. Nothing much you, or anyone, can do, except grow a few grey hair worrying over your manuscript, or simply retract it. Not having seen your manuscript, I can't advise on that. ;-)

Comment: Been there. Likely trouble with reviewers. Nothing you can do but wait! I was in limbo for about 4.5 months for my last paper (the paper was accepted).

Comment: @Shinobii : For how much time it was in "Under review" after coming out of limbo?

Comment: Finally it went into "Under Review" recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means the editor(s) invited reviewers who have not accepted the invitation. If this status has remained the same for 3 months, it's not a good sign. Completing the review can take time, but agreeing to review should be much faster.

My guess is that the editor is either very busy or not very active. He/she invited reviewers and left the manuscript alone. Now would be a good time to nudge the editor and hint that they should be inviting new reviewers, since the currently-invited ones are not likely to agree to review.

Comment: It could also just mean that the status hasn't been updated in any visible way.

Comment: @Buffy it could, but if these statuses are the ones I'm familiar with (using Editorial Manager), then once the reviewer agrees to review the status updates to "Under Review".

Comment: @Allure : I have enquired. The Editorial Manager assured me that the Editor is carefully following and taking good care of the review process. What I have seen in earlier communication with Editor, I have no reason to doubt his interest in the manuscript. He seemed very much interested.

Comment: Earlier communication : https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/125267/102868

Comment: The reviewers could be busy themselves - other things might be higher on their priority list...

Comment: @SolarMike : When the reviewer is invited, do they also recieve the manuscript, and reading which they take decision to whether accept the invitation for review. Or they are usually given just an abstract?

Comment: @user102868 such a good question - probably depends on the editor...

Comment: It could also mean that the reviewer has accepted the review, but he/she forgot to click on "accept", and for some reason the editor hasn't insisted. Possibly they met at a conference and the reviewer accepted verbally.

Comment: @SolarMike if that happens it's good practice to decline to review.

Comment: @user102868 yes, the reviewer receives the manuscript when they are invited - they wouldn't be able to tell whether or not it's interesting otherwise.

Comment: @Allure if all stuck to « good practice » then we would have a lot less questions...

Comment: @user102868 Please edit the additional information into the question proper, so that people will know the context without reading comments to a currently downvoted answer.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni : Finally it went into "Under Review" recently after being in "reviewer invited" state for close to 7 months. If it gets out of that quickly then probably your prediction is right!